# Excel VBA Application.Calculation

Tags: excel, vba

There are multiple times during the day where it is beneficial to turn formula calculations to Manual while I'm working with formulas on large data sets. The problem is that I regularly forget to change formulas back to Automatic and this causes issues later in the day.

I'm looking for a VBA code that will start when Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual (formulas are set to manual) and will open a msgbox every x minutes to remind me that calculations are set to manual.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the Application.OnTime method.

I have borrowed the following code from Chip Pearson's excellent website at http://www.cpearson.com/excel/OnTime.aspx

Just put it in a regular module:

```
Public RunWhen As Double
Public Const cRunIntervalSeconds = 120 ' two minutes
Public Const cRunWhat = "TheSub"  ' the name of the procedure to run

Sub StartTimer()
    RunWhen = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, cRunIntervalSeconds)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub TheSub()
    If Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual Then
        MsgBox "Warning: calculations are manual."
    End If
    StartTimer  ' Reschedule the procedure
End Sub

Sub StopTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunWhen, Procedure:=cRunWhat, Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

Run StartTimer to start the process (you can even put it in the Workbook_Open event if you like). It will check every 2 minutes and if calculations are manual, pop up a warning. Change the 2 minutes to any other value by adjusting the number of seconds declared at the top. I have included the StopTimer sub if you need it.